# Django Admin redirects to 500 error

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, django-admin, uwsgi

I am getting a 500 error when i login to the django admin interface.

I have a ubuntu server 13.10 running nginx uwsgi mysql for my database.

ive set it up following [this tutorial](http://blog.richard.do/index.php/2013/04/setting-up-nginx-django-uwsgi-a-tutorial-that-actually-works/#comment-115) (first time I've set up a django production server)

my settings.py file is as follows

```
"""
Django settings for app_name project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['website.com', 'www.website.com', 'ip_address']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'registration',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'app_name.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_name.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
}
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'Greenwich'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static-only')

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'templates'),
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
)


ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
```

I've managed to run sudo python manage.py syncdb and set up my admin user but when i go to login it redirects me to my 500.html template page.

My uwsgi log file is here

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.13-debian (64bit) on [Mon Feb  3 13:11:22 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.1 on 16 July 2013 02:12:59
os: Linux-3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013
nodename: appname
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /var/www/appname.com/src
writing pidfile to /tmp/project-master.pid
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
setuid() to 33
your processes number limit is 7781
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8889 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:52:09)  [GCC 4.8.1]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1a9f500
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /var/www/appname.com/src/appname/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1a9f500 pid: 13398 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 13398)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 13399, cores: 1)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 1/1] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:11:26 2014]       GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 161 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 2/2] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:13:27 2014]   GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 3/3] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:13:32 2014] GET /admin/ => generated 1865 bytes in 35 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 4/4] 176.62.211.192 () {48 vars in 926 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:13:33 2014] POST /admin/ => generated 1761 bytes in 84 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 3 headers in 121 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 5/5] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:19:05 2014] GET /admin/ => generated 1865 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 6/6] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:19:05 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 7/7] 176.62.211.192 () {48 vars in 926 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:19:07 2014]     POST /admin/ => generated 1761 bytes in 78 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 3 headers in 121 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 8/8] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:30:01 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 9/9] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:30:05 2014] GET /admin/ => generated 1865 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 10/10] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:30:05 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 1761 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 11/11] 176.62.211.192 () {48 vars in 926 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:30:06 2014] POST /admin/ => generated 1761 bytes in 92 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 3 headers in 121 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 12/12] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:00 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 13/13] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:12 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 14/14] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:13 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 15/15] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:13 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 16/16] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:13 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 17/17] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:15 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 18/18] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:31 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 19/19] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:32 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 20/20] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:32 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 21/21] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:32 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 22/22] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:33 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 23/23] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:34 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 24/24] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:31:36 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 25/25] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 730 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:00 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 26/26] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 736 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:27 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 27/27] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:32 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 28/28] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:38 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 29/29] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:38 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 30/30] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:40 2014] GET /admin/ => generated 1865 bytes in 16 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 31/31] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 741 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:40 2014] GET /accounts/register/ => generated 2839 bytes in 7 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 224 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 32/32] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 741 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:32:42 2014] GET /accounts/register/ => generated 2839 bytes in 7 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 224 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 33/33] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 735 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:03 2014] GET /accounts/login/ => generated 2336 bytes in 7 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 34/34] 176.62.211.192 () {48 vars in 951 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:05 2014] POST /accounts/login/ => generated 1761 bytes in 75 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 3 headers in 121 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 35/35] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 735 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:08 2014] GET /accounts/login/ => generated 2336 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 36/36] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 741 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:09 2014] GET /accounts/register/ => generated 2839 bytes in 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 224 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 37/37] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:10 2014] GET /admin/ => generated 1865 bytes in 13 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 38/38] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:10 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 39/39] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:33:10 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 40/40] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:55:37 2014]   GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 41/41] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 705 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:55:41 2014] GET / => generated 1761 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 42/42] 176.62.211.192 () {40 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:55:41 2014] GET /admin/ => generated 1865 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 336 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 [pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 43/43] 176.62.211.192 () {42 vars in 717 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:55:41 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 1761 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 95 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 13399|app: 0|req: 44/44] 176.62.211.192 () {48 vars in 926 bytes} [Mon Feb  3 13:55:45 2014] POST /admin/ => generated 1761 bytes in 71 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 3 headers in 121 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Ive been searching online for a solution but haven't been able to find anything so have resorted to posting on here.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: you should look in uwsgi's logs for the actual error (and post it here if you can't sort out how to fix it :) ). You could also turn the debug on, make the request and turn the debug back off so you can get the error in the page response, but the logs are the right way to look for the error :)

Comment: The settings file is missing `"""` to end the docstring. If it's really not there, add it after the link to the full list of settings, before the line `# Build paths inside the project like this ...`.

Comment: When you show your settings on Stack Overflow, don't share the secret key, it's meant to stay secret!

Comment: @Alasdair - Thanks for pointing that out, also the """ i missed off so have just added it in. (missed it off when i copied form the settings.py)

Comment: @MatteoScotuzzi - il check them now and post up

Comment: So you have connectivity from a browser, but get an HTTP500. This is the default response from django for any uncaught exception from the python code. A logical next step is to set settings.DEBUF=True. Restart the uWSGI processes and retry. Probably you get a nice traceback :)

Comment: Do you see the problem happening in devserver as well?

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer - ive restarted the uWSGI process and i can now see the new homepage i setup instead of the 404 error i had before but i now go to login (admin page) but when i submit the login form just refreshes the page doesn't seem to submit and take me through

Answer (score 0):

I have not fixed this realised that i had SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True which was messing up the login. I've now restarted the uWSGI process and re run the uwsgi.ini and it all work.

Thanks to everyone that helped me resolve this!